# Excel: getall rows for column a if any of b does not contains a text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have data as

```
**COL1**    **COL2**
ABC           1
ABC           2
DEF           1
DEF           2
DEF           3
GHI           1
```

Now I have to get all rows which has col2 not as 3 such that the output is

```
**COL1**    **COL2**
ABC           1
ABC           2
GHI           1
```

Comment: This can be easily achieved using an **AutoFilter.**  See Excel Help.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent not that easily, you need to exclude `DEF` value in column A because it's associated with value 3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Excel tables, add a new column to the table with following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS([Col1],[@Col1],[Col2],3)
```

Or when using ranges:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$A2,$B$2:$B$7,3)
```

Any value other than `0` means that a row exists where column A is the same as current row and column B has value 3. So you can use autofilter to display only the rows with value `0` in this column.

*P.S.: similar solution is also available for [google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlLL52Dep6NCdFNtTldQeE16WTBsYkprcE9fNV91cEE&usp=sharing)*